# Maven / Nexus Integrity Confusion

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I have a project which is dependent to atlassian so I use atlassian maven repo as a repo. And also I have a corporate nexus machine that serves other dependencies.
In a case there is a plugin dependency exists in atlassian maven repo but not in my nexus.I want to use that dependency but it still says I couldnt find the dependency in the nexus repo. It is trying to transfer the artifact to my nexus. I dont want it and I am also not authorized to do that.

Why is it trying to find that in my nexus but not in atlassian repo?
How can I provide it to behave like that?

Thank you for your time.

Here is my settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd"> 
    <offline>false</offline>
    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>com.corporate</pluginGroup>
        <pluginGroup>org.apache.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
        <pluginGroup>org.codehaus.mojo</pluginGroup>
        <pluginGroup>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>

    <servers>       
        <server>
            <id>repo.nexus</id>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>{BMiM7BHIGqUH9Paaz+gUbNSsy22HHZtgtYhOvP8sxI=}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>

    <!-- Profiles -->
    <profiles>      

        <profile>
            <id>pro.tech-atl</id>
            
            <activation>
                <file>
                    <exists>src/main/resources/atlassian-plugin.xml</exists>
                </file>
            </activation>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>repo.atl</id>
                    <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
                    
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    </releases>
                    
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                
                <repository>
                    <id>atlassian-plugin-sdk</id>
                    <url>file://${env.ATLAS_HOME}/repository</url>

                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    </releases>

                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>               
            </repositories>

            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>repo.tech-atl</id>
                    <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
                    
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    </releases>
                    
                    <snapshots>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
                
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>atlassian-plugin-sdk</id>
                    <url>file://${env.ATLAS_HOME}/repository</url>

                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    </releases>

                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>pro.tech-java</id>
            
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>repo.nexus</id>
                    <name>Enterprise Maven Repository for Java</name>
                    <url>https://nexus/content/groups/java/</url>

                    <releases>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>

                    <snapshots>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>repo.nexus</id>
                    <name>Enterprise Maven Repository for Maven Plugins</name>
                    <url>https://nexus/content/groups/java/</url>

                    <releases>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>

                    <snapshots>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>           
        </profile>
                
        <!-- Global Properties -->
        <profile>
            <id>sys.properties</id>
            
            <properties>
                <!-- Properties for SDLC applications. URLS's should not contain trailing slash. -->
                <sys.hostName>dev.blabla.com</sys.hostName>     
                
                <app.web.hostName>${sys.hostName}</app.web.hostName><!-- Private -->
                <app.web.baseUrl>https://${app.web.hostName}</app.web.baseUrl>
                <app.common.hostName>${sys.hostName}</app.common.hostName><!-- Public -->
                <app.common.baseUrl>https://${app.common.hostName}</app.common.baseUrl>
                
                <app.jira.baseUrl>${app.web.baseUrl}/jira</app.jira.baseUrl>
                <app.confluence.baseUrl>${app.web.baseUrl}/confluence</app.confluence.baseUrl>
                <app.stash.baseUrl>${app.web.baseUrl}/stash</app.stash.baseUrl>
                <app.bamboo.baseUrl>${app.web.baseUrl}/bamboo</app.bamboo.baseUrl>
                <app.fecru.baseUrl>${app.web.baseUrl}/fecru</app.fecru.baseUrl>
                <app.sonarqube.baseUrl>${app.web.baseUrl}/sonarqube</app.sonarqube.baseUrl>
                <app.nexus.baseUrl>${app.web.baseUrl}/nexus</app.nexus.baseUrl>
                <app.nexus.repo.releaseUrl>${app.web.baseUrl}/nexus</app.nexus.repo.releaseUrl>
                <app.git.baseUrl>ssh://git@${sys.hostName}:7999</app.git.baseUrl>               
            </properties>           
        </profile>
    </profiles>
  
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>sys.properties</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>pro.tech-atl</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>pro.tech-java</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Please add the `settings.xml` in which you defined the repositories.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I have added my settings.xml now.Thank you

Comment: Is there a group that contains both repos?  I suspect that'd be adviced to use as well as make your settings simpler.